# sqlite autoincrement function

Tags: android, sqlite, auto-increment

I am writing an app that controls many tables in a database. I am using the AUTOINCREMENT method of sqlite. The items corresponding to the AUTOINCREMENT '_id' collumn will be having their unique ids as the values in the '_id column'

Is it advisable to use this method to assign unique ids to every item. Because i donot know what will happen to the numbering system if I write a method to remove certain rows from the table.

I mean that if once the table is created with certain entries and then the user decides to remove certain rows, will the autoincrement column re-number itself (which will lead to wrong ids being assigned to the corresponding items) or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting rows from a table will not reset the auto increment ID.  That is, suppose you have created rows 1, 2 and 3.  If you delete 2, the next row you insert will still have an ID of 4, i.e, you would now have rows 1, 3, 4 in the database.